# Xbox One App Beta Crashes when starting Streaming

Tags: crash, streaming, xbox-one

Since a few days only the Windows 10 Xbox One App **Beta** crashes as soon as I hit the button to start streaming.

The event log shows 1 critical error followed by an informational one:

```
Faulting application name: XboxApp.exe, version: 33.34.1710.13002, time stamp: 0x59e0f905
Faulting module name: Windows.UI.Xaml.dll, version: 10.0.15063.674, time stamp: 0xaf452875
Exception code: 0xc000027b
Fault offset: 0x0000000000443b5f
Faulting process id: 0x4f8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d348569af72294
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.XboxAppBeta_33.34.13002.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\XboxApp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.Xaml.dll
Report Id: c0878d24-95ef-4f30-8c63-9d63fd66ba72
Faulting package full name: Microsoft.XboxAppBeta_33.34.13002.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Faulting package-relative application ID: Microsoft.XboxAppBeta
```

Followed by:

```
Fault bucket 133563162776, type 5
Event Name: MoAppCrash
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: Microsoft.XboxAppBeta_33.34.13002.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
P2: praid:Microsoft.XboxAppBeta
P3: 33.34.1710.13002
P4: 59e0f905
P5: combase.dll
P6: 10.0.15063.608
P7: b66dc19d
P8: 80070005
P9: 0000000000021bd9
P10: 

Attached files:
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER49.tmp.dmp
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER1F0.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER1FE.tmp.csv
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER20F.tmp.txt

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_Microsoft.XboxAp_34778c3b6cd461ace843f7226689e8a9398c3a_adf3c325_16f8071f

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: c0878d24-95ef-4f30-8c63-9d63fd66ba72
Report Status: 268435456
```

Nothing has changed from "user perspective" undoubtly something has changed somewhere. The Xbox One has the correct settings. TEST of streaming from the app shows all green checkmarks.

Part of the logs:

```
Version=1
EventType=MoAppCrash
EventTime=131528351571829391
ReportType=2
Consent=1
UploadTime=131528351577312331
ReportStatus=268435456
ReportIdentifier=a4955702-008c-4db2-a908-a09a3eca5bc6
IntegratorReportIdentifier=c0878d24-95ef-4f30-8c63-9d63fd66ba72
Wow64Host=34404
NsAppName=praid:Microsoft.XboxAppBeta
AppSessionGuid=000004f8-0001-0010-9422-f79a5648d301
TargetAppId=U:Microsoft.XboxAppBeta_33.34.13002.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe!Microsoft.XboxAppBeta
TargetAppVer=33.34.13002.0_x64_!2017//10//13:17:33:57!0!XboxApp.exe
BootId=4294967295
TargetAsId=2234
Response.BucketId=6d50f37727144b9648deb309e94eeec5
Response.BucketTable=5
Response.LegacyBucketId=133563162776
Response.type=4
Sig[0].Name=Package Full Name
Sig[0].Value=Microsoft.XboxAppBeta_33.34.13002.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Sig[1].Name=Application Name
Sig[1].Value=praid:Microsoft.XboxAppBeta
Sig[2].Name=Application Version
Sig[2].Value=33.34.1710.13002
Sig[3].Name=Application Timestamp
Sig[3].Value=59e0f905
Sig[4].Name=Fault Module Name
Sig[4].Value=combase.dll
Sig[5].Name=Fault Module Version
Sig[5].Value=10.0.15063.608
Sig[6].Name=Fault Module Timestamp
Sig[6].Value=b66dc19d
Sig[7].Name=Exception Code
Sig[7].Value=80070005
Sig[8].Name=Exception Offset
Sig[8].Value=0000000000021bd9
DynamicSig[1].Name=OS Version
DynamicSig[1].Value=10.0.15063.2.0.0.256.48
DynamicSig[2].Name=Locale ID
DynamicSig[2].Value=1033
DynamicSig[22].Name=Additional Information 1
DynamicSig[22].Value=d94c
DynamicSig[23].Name=Additional Information 2
DynamicSig[23].Value=d94c9dc17773636ff9981b014aff5348
DynamicSig[24].Name=Additional Information 3
DynamicSig[24].Value=1cf3
DynamicSig[25].Name=Additional Information 4
DynamicSig[25].Value=1cf34613c43d117916e31de6d1bb4b49
UI[2]=C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.XboxAppBeta_33.34.13002.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\XboxApp.exe
................
State[0].Key=Transport.DoneStage1
State[0].Value=1
FriendlyEventName=Stopped working
ConsentKey=MoAppCrash
AppName=Microsoft.XboxAppBeta_8wekyb3d8bbwe!Microsoft.XboxAppBeta
AppPath=C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.XboxAppBeta_33.34.13002.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\XboxApp.exe
NsPartner=windows
NsGroup=windows8
ApplicationIdentity=D928AFE81E4F0050B26896B950CCCAAC
MetadataHash=-89736816
```

Comment: Are you using 1703 or 1709?

Comment: @Ramhound 1703 {15063.674 , could be that maybe a KB windows update delivered the passed days messed things up. Would have been https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4041676/windows-10-update-kb4041676

Comment: So uninstall the update if you believe it’s the cause.

Comment: Just now found out that the Xbox App is working , the problem only occurs with the Xbox App Beta.

Comment: I was wondering the reason you were using a beta version of the application

Comment: Interest. But since its beta only I will report it at MS for the beta and this once can probably be closed. When I posted this I had not tried the non beta one.

Comment: It shouldn’t be closed it should be **self-answered**